# Close an active state on a button when pressing a secondary button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having issues in closing the active state on my footer button. When you click **footer** it will slide a hidden div pushing the fix div up and changing the word footer to close, with a background color for its active state. Once you click close the div will slide down and the wording will change back to footer and the active state is hidden.

**The issue**

when I click the menu button it does not change the active state on the footer button. The div will slide down but the wording will not change from close to footer and the background color will not change.

**The JS**

```
$('#more').click(function () {
    var open = $('header').is('.open');
    $('#footerPanel')['slide' + (open ? 'Up' : 'Down')](400);
    $('header').animate({
        bottom: (open ? '-' : '+') + '=120'
    }, 400, function () {
        $('header').toggleClass('open');
    });                 
});
$('#menu').click(function () {
    if ($('header').is('.open')) {
        $('header').removeClass('open').animate({'bottom': "-=120"});
        $('#footerPanel').slideUp(400);
    }
});
$('.footerButton').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('footerButton');
    if($this.hasClass('footerButton')){
        $this.text('Footer');           
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this.text('Close');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('activetoggle');
});
```

My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigant841/XqUp4/2/).
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I thought this looked familiar. :)

Comment: yes it does lol just having one more issue @Neil Kistner thank you for your help last time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following function as a callback for the `animate` function when clicking your menu button. It will check to see if the footer button is in the active state, and if so will update accordingly, otherwise it will leave it be.

```
function () {
    var $footer = $('.activetoggle');

    if ($footer.length)
        $footer
            .toggleClass('activetoggle footerButton')
            .text('Footer');
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wyze/XqUp4/4/)